# Operations Resarch Optimal Scheduling

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, operations-research

Consider the following problem:

> A car manufacturing company needs to transport car frames, which are $10$ cubic units each, and wheels, which are $2$ cubic units each, across the Atlantic ocean. They use boats which have 50 cubic units of storage space to transport the frames, and planes which have $20$ cubic units of storage space to transport the tires. Each car needs $4$ wheels, so if $x$ is the number of cars to transport then $4x$ is the number of wheels.
>
> The company wants to minimize the total wasted space when they ship.  For example, if they choose to transport $16$ cars ($160$ cubic units) and $16\cdot4=64$ wheels ($128$ cubic units), then they will need $4$ boats and $7$ planes, and will have $40+12= 52$ units of wasted space.

I'm interested in algorithms for solving this type of problem, given a desired range of solutions, i.e.  $10< x < 15$.  The obvious answer is to use the LCM to find a perfect solution, but what if there is no perfect solution within the range?

Any thoughts or research papers on this topic would be very helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=$ number of cars to build, $S=$ the number of ships to use, and $P=$ the number of planes to use. Let $L,U$ be the lower and upper production range for $X$.

We want to minimize the objective function: $Z(S,P,X)=50S+20P-12X$

Subject to constraints:

- $50S-10X \geq 0$
- $20P-8X\geq0$
- $L\leq X \leq U$
- $P,S\geq 0$
- $X,P,S \in \mathbb{N}$

An this is a linear integer program. You can tackle it using the [Branch and Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm, as implemented in any integer programming package.

Comment: Cool. Branch and bound has worst case exponential complexity, iirc.  Any polynomial algorithms?

Comment: @stochman yes..but so does simplex and yet its still useful.

Comment: @stochman in many cases, a first run of the simplex algorithm on the linear program version (with non-integral variables) will be integral off the bat. I wouldn't worry about worst case. For example, the Ellipsoid Method for linear programs is theoretically polynomial time, but in practice it usually takes longer than the simplex algorithm, which has exponential worst case.